# Need to get the expected output in python(Problem explained in description)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am developing an data extractor using **regular expression in python.**
I stuck somewhere my other code is running in which I created in regex but the this code which is mentioned below:

**regex code:**

```
regexCode='^about_company:\n[\s\S]+?[A-Z]:'
```

The above code is not working properly when I run in python I think , I made a mistake because the regex code is running properly [here](https://regex101.com/r/aook5u/1)

**Expected output:**

[The output should look like this is terminal of pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQGXU.png)

sorry for links,I cannot put the pics directly because of reputation issues

**Python Code:**

```
import re

filename = open('textFile.txt','r')
rege = '^about_company:[\s\S]+?[A-Z]:|ABOUT COMPANY:[\s\S]+?[A-Z]:'
for data in filename:
    matches = re.findall(rege, data, re.MULTILINE)
    if matches:
        print(matches)
```

When I tried to print the data by storing the data into text then it worked but when I tried to read the data from the file it shows the empty lists.
Text file is same as in the regex101's link.
I need solution of this please please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the whole file into memory and run the regex against the whole text:

```
import re

f = open('28985133.dat','r')
data = f.read()                # Read the file contents into a var
rege = r'^about_company:[\s\S]+?[A-Z]:|ABOUT COMPANY:[\s\S]+?[A-Z]:'
matches = re.findall(rege, data, re.MULTILINE) # Collect matches
for s in matches:              # Loop through matches
    print(s)                   # Print matches
```

Comment: It prints the whole result into a single line

Comment: That is what your console shows. In reality, that is a multiline result. If you want to see it in the console use `for s in matches: print(s)`